# hotplug_slot_attr_power.attr never set, how it has value?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, pci

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d01e12dd3f4227f1be5d7c5bffa7b8240787bec1/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L301

```
if (has_power_file(pci_slot)) {
    retval = sysfs_create_file(&pci_slot->kobj,
                   &hotplug_slot_attr_power.attr); ////// why .attr has value here ?
    if (retval)
        goto exit_power;
}
```

In this part of PCI code, it calling sysfs_create_file(), but I can't find where the

```
hotplug_slot_attr_power.attr
```

was set.

Comment: also that hotplug_slot_attr_power.store was never called.

Comment: The structure `hotplug_slot_attr_power` is **statically initialized** in the same 
 file: [drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c:120](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d01e12dd3f4227f1be5d7c5bffa7b8240787bec1/drivers/pci/hotplug/pci_hotplug_core.c#L120), this includes initialization of its fields. If you want to understand meaning of attributes and their fields, you may read [sysfs documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt).